# Kafka-Node HighLevelProducer sends all messages to only one partition

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, kafka-node

I have a Kafka producer written in NodeJS using the Kafka-Node library.  The producer works, except for the topic the message are being sent to only gets placed into 1 partition (partition 0).  The topic has 4 partitions but no message ever goes to those other partitions.  Im using the HighLevelProducer from the Kafka-Node library.  I thought that the HighLevelProducer produces the message to go to all the available partitions in a round robin fashion.

The code is simple, but maybe im missing something to make sure it round robins instead of just dumping all messages into one partition.

```
const messages = data.map(JSON.stringify)
        console.log(`Sending ${data.length} Messages`)
        producer.send([{ topic, messages }], (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            console.log(`Sent Messages`)
            resolve()
        })
```

Code of what I have tried expected for messages to go to all 4 available partitions

```
const messages = data.map(JSON.stringify)
        console.log(`Sending ${data.length} Messages`)
        producer.send([{ topic, messages }], (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            console.log(`Sent Messages`)
            resolve()
        })
```

Comment: Can you also show your `sample message` and `partition_key`?

Comment: Also, Can you paste the output of using this API: https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#describegroupsconsumergroups-cb

Comment: I'm not using partition_key in the message (null key messages).  The messages are simple JSON message items...
Like...
{
   "item1":"item one value",
   "item2":"item two value"
}

Comment: In the callback, can you show what `data` returns? Secondly, `kafka-node` hasnt been updated in 3+ years. You may want to try `kafkajs` instead.